# What is the most efficient way to have two "blogs" on one site?

Tags: multisite

**What I want:**

Two wordpress blogs with separate cats and tags

```
reggi.com/portfolio/category/example
reggi.com/blog/category/example
reggi.com/portfolio/tags/example
reggi.com/blog/tags/example
```

Site root to not be wordpress or to be a static page with custom template

```
reggi.com/ <-- NOT wordpress
reggi.com/portfolio <-- wordpress
reggi.com/blog <-- wordpress
```

One theme directory

**What I have tried so far:**

I have installed one wordpress theme in the root `reggi.com` and had a plugin which removed `category` from `reggi.com/category/portfolio`. This worked but my permalink structure was really sluggish as for each post was queried first with `%category%`. I also ran into problems with the tags where it was skipping over the category in the url and displaying something like `reggi.com/tags/example` rather than `reggi.com/portfolio/tags/example`.

I have installed multisite but I am running into problems where I need to display different indexes for `/portfolio` and `/blog` I am thinking my only option would be to have the template index look at the url and if it is `/blog` or `/portfolio` display the respective themes accordingly. Is this wise? I don't know how to setup `/blog` with multisite post [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/536/how-do-i-get-blog-on-my-wordpres-multisite).

Are there any other ways to go about this? Something I'm missing? Should I just have two separate wordpress installs?

Comment: Why are you not using WP for your main site as well?

Comment: The homepage is going to be a static page but not involve any wordpress functionality. I am making the homepage a "activity" page which will aggregate all of my internet traffic like twitter, delicious, and dailybooth etc.

Answer (score 1):

Create two custom post types, one for each blog. Then you can add custom taxonomies to each one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Then I suggest you use WP for you main site as well.

Just create a custom template like this:

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Start page */

  // Here you add custom PHP code.
  // It does not have to contain a single WP code
?>
```

Then you just use create two more pages and call them `portfolio` and `blog`.
In these pages you only list posts with specific categories.

Comment: This is exactly what I did in my first (non-multisite) attempt. The problem with this is that I need to have the tag queries seporated with different displays ie. `example.com/blog/tags/example` looks different from `example.com/portfolio/tags/example` I'm thinking that I use get_tags() and stick `/portfolio` or `/blog` respectively into the string. But I would then need to pull the url and parse it in index template file. Is this really the best way?

Comment: But is this really 3 different sites? Or is it just a main site with different sections? Because I don't think it will matter to much for the user of the tags become `example.com/tags/sometag`. I'm no experte, but what if you drop tags and use custom made category trees and then check what category tree it is, and based on that, aither re-route or change look and feel? I think I'm still not quite sure what you are trying to achieve here :)